# How to pass user id and type in table from controller for polymorphic assosiation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, polymorphic-associations

I have been struggling all day to pass a user ID and type into tagging table  when I create my new tagging

In the **Tagging** Controller i have this code:

```
def create
    @taggable = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    @tagger = current_user
    @tagging = @taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tagging.save!
        format.js {render status: :created}       
      end
    end
  end
```

In this **Tagging** Model i have this code

```
 belongs_to :taggable, :polymorphic => true
 belongs_to :tagger, :polymorphic => true
```

In this **Blog** Model i have this code

```
attr_accessible :description,:user_id,:title,:taggings_attributes,:tagger_attributes
 has_many :taggings, as: :taggable
 has_many :tagger, as: :taggable,:class_name=>"Tagging"
```

Now I want something like this

```
@tagging = @taggable.@tagger.taggings.build(params[:taggings])
```

Comment: How about `@taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings], tagger: current_user)`

Comment: Hi @DamienRoche Thanks for your response.
After using your code
`@tagging = @taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings], tagger: current_user)`

I get -
**Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tagger**

How to fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Didn't realise you were on Rails 3, oops. When you see this in the future, you would add `attr_accessible :attribute_name` to the model. However, do NOT do that for attributes which shouldn't be accessible to users. In this case, as @hjing's answer says, use `@tagging.tagger = @tagger.user`.

Comment: correction: should be `@tagging.tagger = @tagger`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the user anytime after you build the new `Tag` object and before you save it.

For example,

```
@tagging = @taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings])
@tagging.tagger_id = @tagger.user.id
@tagging.tagger_type = 'User'
```

You can also assign the user directly, rather than the tagger_id and tagger_type.

```
@tagging = @taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings])
@tagging.tagger = @tagger.user
```

Comment: Hi @hjing Thanks for your response.
After using your code
`@tagging = @taggable.taggings.build(params[:taggings], tagger: @tagger)`

I get -
**Can't mass-assign protected attributes: tagger**

How to fix it?
thanks.

Comment: Please, do NOT make `:user` an accessible attribute! That will allow the users to override `:user` assignment for the `tagging`, where it should be ensured via `current_user`.

Comment: @DamienRoche you're absolutely right, wasn't really thinking when I typed this answer